# Non-http communication between two containers in Azure Container Apps

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

I'm trying to deploy two containers in Azure Container Apps. The two containers are placed in the same Container Environment.

The "architecture" is as follows:
`Public HTTPS ==> Container A ==(gRPC port 7345)==> Container B`

`Container A` can talk to `Container B` over HTTP if I configure `Container B` with `--target-port:80 --ingress=internal`.

Now, what do I do if they are to communicate over a non-HTTP protocol? like gRPC, redis, etc.? I haven't figured out the right combination?
Do I have to set up vNet integration for that?

Thanks!